# Removing User from TFS2013

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

A developer has left our team. Whilst working with us, he was a member of our TFS2013 instance. I've removed him from every group within the Team Project and Team Project Collection, and checked that he is not in any groups on the TFS server directly. His account in active directory has in fact been deleted. However, I still see his name in two places;

1) On the drop down list for 'Assigned To' on tasks/backlog items on the Scrum board

2) On the Team Project Collection Users list, his user appears if you select 'Users' but he is not a member of any groups. There is no Remove option anywhere on the screen.

Is this simply because he has previously checked in code/had tasks assigned to him in the past? I realise it is easy to say 'yes' to this question as it seems perhaps obvious, but I would like to know if it is possible to completely remove his user from these 2 places.

Comment: I am having this same issue the user doesn't seam to be a member of any groups.

Answer (score 0):

1) First check if he isn't part of any teams and/or an admin of a team (under the team icon). If the Witd types are customized, it can also be that he was manualy added. Otherwise force a synchronisation of the active directory; https://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2013/12/29/force-synchronizing-tfs-2013-users-with-windows-accounts/

2) If the synchronisation didn't fix this as well, its possible there are explicit rights defined on his user account. You need to remove that specific right.